# std::regex expressions in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to use really straightforward regular expressions to match strings like `2001M12`. I create a `std::regex` object as follows:

```
std::regex gretlMonth("^[:d:]{4}M[:d:]{2}$");
```

but I get the following runtime exception on this line:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "Plot_GuessesTimeFormat": std::runtime_error: regex_error
```

What  am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gcc, libstdc++ has not yet implemented regex.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

See also:

[Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)
[No matches with c++11 regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex)
[C++0x regex in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716680/c0x-regex-in-gcc/4716974#4716974)
[very basic regex scenario works different than my expectation on libstdc++-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804823/very-basic-regex-scenario-works-different-than-my-expectation-on-libstdc-v3/9805087#9805087)
[C++11 RegEx Matching - I can't get it to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148767/c11-regex-matching-i-cant-get-it-to-work-properly/12149148#12149148)
[No matches with c++11 regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex/11269782#11269782)
[Regular Expressions misunderstanding or just broken implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696063/regular-expressions-misunderstanding-or-just-broken-implementation/7701540#7701540)
[c++ std regex question mark issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987278/c-std-regex-question-mark-issue/15987489#15987489)
[What is my mistake in this regular expression using std::regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504296/what-is-my-mistake-in-this-regular-expression-using-stdregex/13504491#13504491)
[std::regex -- is there some lib that needs to be linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623250/stdregex-is-there-some-lib-that-needs-to-be-linked/1845056#1845056)
[Error while trying to compile c++11 regex tutorial with Clang++ on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386531/error-while-trying-to-compile-c11-regex-tutorial-with-clang-on-linux/17221959#17221959)
[Is this C++11 regex error me or the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler/8060116#8060116)
[C++11 Regex Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169553/c11-regex-grouping/13169673#13169673)

Comment: Crap! Is this functionality also available in boost?

Comment: Yes.  It's available in either boost or libc++ (from clang)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your regex string is incorrect and try this "^\d{4}M\d{2}$".